# How to set container element scrollable with overflow to visible for some element?

Tags: html, css

I want to show the element floating outside the parent container. But, container element has lot other controls. So, i have set the css property `overflow:auto` and fixed the height to make the container scrollable. but, I want the floating element should be visible even across the container.

Run the following code in snippet to understand the issue.

I hope you get it.

```css
div.container{  
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;  
  background: #e4f0f5;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;  
}
div#float{
  background: #d4dde4;
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<strong>Start</strong>
<br /><br />
<div class='container' style="overflow: visible;">
  <label> Field 1 :</label><input type="text"><br/>
  <button id='modal'>
  <strong>Click Here</strong>
  </button><br />
  
    <div id='float'>
        <strong>This floating element looks OK.</strong>
    </div>
  
  <label> Field 4 :</label><input type="text"><br/>
  <label> Field 5 :</label><input type="text">
</div>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<div class='container' style="overflow-y: auto;">
  <label> Field 1 :</label><input type="text"><br/>
  <button id='modal'>
  <strong>Click Here</strong>
  </button><br />
  
    <div id='float'>
        <strong>But, this is not. It should overflow from the container</strong>
    </div>
  
  <label> Field 4 :</label><input type="text"><br/>
  <label> Field 5 :</label><input type="text">
  <label> Field 6 :</label><input type="text"><br/>
  <label> Field 7 :</label><input type="text">
  <label> Field 8 :</label><input type="text"><br/>
  <label> Field 9 :</label><input type="text">
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<strong>End Of Page</strong>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ - not sure if that will work if you want the overlap in the same “direction” as you’re scrolling though (in this article, it is the other direction) - you’ll have to try and see.

Comment: I did not understand the expected behavior, but try removing position relative from container.

Comment: @Gildor I did it. but, it freez the panel at the fixed location. Actually I have created a customized dropdown control and placed inside a container which is set `overflow` css property to `auto` (scrollable). So, if user scroll down the container the dropdown popup should be also scrolled.